# Lightning bumpfee completes but doesnt create a new transaction. Instead it waits in "pending sweeps"

Tags: lightning-network, ln-opening-channels, child-pays-for-parent

I had a Lightning channel open transaction pending for 24 hours due to a low fee.

So I issued a bumpfee for the output index like so:

```
lncli wallet bumpfee --sat_per_byte <new_fee> <txid>:<output index>
```

This completed with a return value of 0.

However a new transaction was never created.

Instead there is an output in the command:

```
lncli wallet pendingsweeps
```

where I see the <new_fee> specified and the "outpoint" being the txid:output_index value

So what do I need to do to complete this CPFP operation?

Answer (score 1):

My bitcoind didn't have the parent txn so the bumpfee never completed.

I restarted my bitcoind, lnd, rebroadcasted a raw txn that I got from another node's mempool and issued a bumpfee again.

A new txn was confirmed shortly after